# Segue to replace UISplitViewController master view

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

We have a a basic UISplitViewController Storyboard.  We are attempting to add a Navigation Bar icon on the master screen which links to a new view but we can't get this to work as desired.  Here's what we have with the arrow pointing to the new icon:

[image]

We want this to work like Apple Mail where you click the icon and the new view appears in the Master view such as when you click Edit:

[image]

[image]

But after adjusting the segue settings the best I can do is to use Show Detail which shows the new screen in the Detail view.

How can you get the new view to show in the master view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was right in front of me:

- Kind: Present Modally
- Presentation: Current Context

The Presentation setting is what I was missing.....

[image]